# Akka Siblings Recursive ActorRef requirement

Tags: scala, design-patterns, akka, actor, service-discovery

Allow me to abstract the problem I quite often face with actors, and what the common design pattern to solve it. Suppose I have the following actor hierarchy:

```
── user
    └── ServiceActor
        ├── TicketManager
        │   ├── WorkerA
        │   ├── WorkerB
        │   └── WorkerC
        └── UserManager
            ├── WorkerA
            ├── WorkerB
            └── WorkerC
```

The hierarchy beyond the first level, i.e Ticket and User Managers are unimportant. I have a requirement that TicketManager fires messages to UserManager and vice versa. (Note that these are just example names I've used and is not representative of any real problem)

Which of the following is the most appropriate?

Option 1:

TicketManager constructor takes UserManager as a constructor argument.
UserManager constructor takes TicketManager as a constructor argument.
However, both can't have recursive calls to each other, so this is probably not possible anyway.

Option 2:

UserManager makes a reference to TicketManager via an actorSelection as actorSelection("../TicketManager") and so on on requirement, or only once on startup and keeps it.

Option 3:

At any given point of time, UserManager/TicketManager asks their parent (ServiceActor) for a reference to their other sibling and is appropriately replied back with an actorRef as the parent holds that reference.

Option 4:

Should this never be a situation? Should I not think of siblings talking to each other as it "complicates" design in some way? Should there be a more tree-like hierarchy? What is a common design pattern that may help avoid it if that's the case?

I hope I've made the requirement clear, please allow me to clarify further if needed?

Comment: While the initialize tactic suggested by Edmondo was insightful, I ended up doing a mixture of Option 4 and Option 3. Option 4 to untangle the mess of my actor hierarchy. Beyond that, at any point that there was a need for siblings to talk to each other, they talked via their parent. I think that's a reasonable pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Option 4 is the probably the best approach if the dependency become complex, however for two actors you could simply use a message to initialize them: actor are designed to keep mutable state, so it's fine if you mutate it.

So I would say the parent actor, responsible to create TickerManager and ActorManager could do the following

```
case class InitializeTicketManager(userManager:ActorRef)

case class InitializeUserManager(ticketManager:ActorRef)
val userManager = context.actorOf(...)
val ticketManager = context.actorOf(...)
userManager ! InitializeUserManager(ticketManager)
ticketManager ! InitializeTicketManager(userManager)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, what if we had more than just two actors? What if I had managers for ticket, user, kiosk etc at the same flat level right under the top level ServiceActor, with each not having sufficient sub-responsibilities to each other to create a deeper tree? Do you still suggest initializing via the init method?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using more than one ActorSystem what you were looking would be some sort of ServiceDiscovery. Also these will help (Cluster Routing, Cluster Sharding, ClusterRouterGroup).

Your's is simpler, you have only one ActorSystem. I would use Option1 with a twist of lazy vals and call-by-names i.e

```
package sumnulu

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorRef, Props}

/**
  * Created by sumnulu
  */
class RootActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  lazy val serviceA: ActorRef = context.actorOf(ServiceA.props(serviceB))
  lazy val serviceB: ActorRef = context.actorOf(ServiceB.props(serviceA))

  override def preStart() = {
    log info "Root Actor Ready"
    serviceA ! "test"
  }

  override def receive = Actor.ignoringBehavior
}

class ServiceA(serviceB: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  println("serviceA constructor")
  serviceB ! "Hi"


  override def receive: Receive = {
    case x => println(s"self:$self from:$sender msg:$x")
  }
}


class ServiceB(serviceA: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  println("serviceB constructor")
  serviceA ! "Hi"

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case x => println(s"self:$self from:$sender msg:$x")
  }

}

//call-by-name important is i.e `=>` 
object ServiceA {
  def props(serviceB: => ActorRef) = Props(new ServiceA(serviceB))
}

//call-by-name important is i.e `=>` 
object ServiceB {
  def props(serviceA: => ActorRef) = Props(new ServiceB(serviceA))
}

object RootActor {
  def props = Props[RootActor]
}
```

---

```
[info] [INFO] [02/18/2017 17:49:52.485] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Main/user/app] Root Actor Ready
[info] serviceA constructor
[info] serviceB constructor
[info] self:Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$a#1420483478] from:Actor[akka://Main/user/app#274353135] msg:test
[info] self:Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$b#1573183992] from:Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$a#1420483478] msg:Hi
[info] self:Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$a#1420483478] from:Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$b#1573183992] msg:Hi
```

Comment: Oh wow! Never thought of it like this. While I do understand the difference in call-by-value and call-by-name, why exactly does this solve the problem? Could you adding some detail on that?